# Error from Unix make util: `then' unmatched

Tags: unix, makefile

Following error returned after trying to run makefile:

```
    @if [ ! -z "$(WL_BASE)" ]; then \
    $(DIR_JAVA_WEB_BUILD)/JavaWSWebLogicInstall! \
    fi
    @if [ ! -z "$(GF_HOME)" ]; then \
    $(DIR_JAVA_WEB_BUILD)/JavaWSGlassfishInstall! \
    fi
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb and suggest that you're missing a couple of semicolons. Try:

```
@if [ ! -z "$(WL_BASE)" ]; then \
$(DIR_JAVA_WEB_BUILD)/JavaWSWebLogicInstall! ; \
fi
@if [ ! -z "$(GF_HOME)" ]; then \
$(DIR_JAVA_WEB_BUILD)/JavaWSGlassfishInstall! ; \
fi
```

If that doesn't work, try something simpler. Verify that this works from the command line:

```
@if [ ! -z "$(WL_BASE)" ]; then $(DIR_JAVA_WEB_BUILD)/JavaWSWebLogicInstall! fi
```

and tell us the result (make sure to define `$(DIR_JAVA_WEB_BUILD)` first), and we'll go from there.

Comment: You'd need a semi-colon after the exclamation mark in the one-liner version.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: only if the semicolons are the solution, in which case the OP won't need the one-line version.

Comment: Have faith in your diagnosis.  The semi-colons are the solution; their absence is the problem...unless the user is managing to use a totally non-standard shell.